# convergence of a series involving cosines

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Question:

1) How to determine the convergence of

> $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k^{\alpha} x)}{k^{\alpha}} (-1)^k $

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1]$. I am especially interested in the case of $\alpha = 1/2$.

2) For a fixed $\alpha$, if the above series converges for every $x$, is the convergence uniform? Is the resulting sum bounded in $x$?

I found the series tests (alternating test,etc.) I learned not useful in this situation, except that the convergence is clear for $x = 0$...

Comment: Looks like a lacunary Fourier series. Have you seen http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183525927 already?

Comment: ...and this: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1962-1964__15_/CM_1962-1964__15__28_0/CM_1962-1964__15__28_0.pdf too; Kolmogorov's theorem seems to be the key.

Comment: thanks, but i thought lacunary means $a_k$ grows exponentially? here $k^{\alpha}$ does not.

Comment: Have you tried things like the Van-Corput method? It should be applicable here ...

Comment: @ Helge: Can you give me a reference please? I never heard of it before...

Comment: It's in the '10 lectures' book by Montgomery. I am not sure, where one can find it on the internet.

Comment: @mr.gondolier: For the case $\alpha = 1/2$, I suggest writing the series as $(a_1 - a_2) + (a_3 - a_4) + \cdots$, applying the mean value theorem, and considering http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27123/pointwise-convergence-of-sum-frac-sin-sqrtnxn/27160#27160.